# BigchainDB issue with send_commit

Tags: bigchaindb

I am learning BigchainDB and I am trying to store a payload on the blockchain with the following code:

```
alice = generate_keypair()
metadata = {'planet': 'earth'}
bicycle = {
   'data': {
    'bicycle': {
         'serial_number': 'abcd1234',
         'manufacturer': 'bkfab',
    },
    },
}
tx = bdb.transactions.prepare(
    operation='CREATE',
    signers=alice.public_key,
    asset=bicycle,
    metadata=metadata,
)
signed_tx = bdb.transactions.fulfill(tx,private_keys=alice.private_key)
sent_creation_tx = bdb.transactions.send_commit(signed_tx)
return sent_creation_tx
```

I got a 500 from the send_commit.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi! Are you getting an error ? Can you share the details of bigchaindb collection from mongodb ?

Comment: Hi, I am getting a 500 and an HTML page is returned instead of a payload

Comment: Is the root URL is correct ?  is BCDB is running ? Also tendermint is running too ?

Comment: I was sending requests to bdb = BigchainDB('https://test.bigchaindb.com') as per tutorial on https://www.bigchaindb.com/. No idea I had to user tendermint.

Comment: Is there a complete tutorial on this? My use case is storing key-value on bigchaindb

Comment: Sorry There isn't any proper tutorial on this. Each site has its own chunk of information. My suggestion is that you first read the official documentation from https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb-driver before you start any coding. once you get the idea about things then do coding. First try to compile the alice and bob example (mentioned in docs) and observe mongodb. You'll get the idea.

Comment: You need to determine the root url then proceed ahead. Most likely it would be localhost:9984 (depends on your configuration).

Comment: Did you resolve the issue ? please post your findings which might be useful for others.

Comment: Sometimes it's because of the same transaction(data), but if you facing it for your first transaction then check the root url.